# nats: error: consumer name already in use (10013)

Tags: nats.io

An edit to `maxAckPending` in NATS CLI is throwing below error:

> nats: error: consumer name already in use (10013)

Below command is being used:

```
nats consumer edit --max-pending=25000
```